# handling special characters in oracle xml

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I am using dbms_xmlgen package to generate xml for my given query. the xml generation failed when the query result contains control characters.

```
ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed.
```

then i set dbms_xmlgen.setconvertspecialchars flag to false , restarted the query and manually trimmed off control characters using REGEX_REPLACE.

Since i turn off dbms_xmlgen.setconvertspecialchars , the special charcaters in the xml contents were not got converted . I tried CONVERT function which treats my xml as varchar and converting even the xml tags.

after trimming control characters off i have xml like below

```
<a>Something < Something </a>
```

i need this to converted to `<a>Something &lt; Something </a>`**(Expected)**
but CONVERT gives me `&lt;a&gt;Something &lt; Something &lt;/a&gt;`**(Actual)**

Please help me here. Thanks in advance